# Win32 Debugging Macros

Tags: debugging, winapi

What is the standard macro used to write text to the output window in Win32 (outside MFC)?
I am looking for something which the pre-processor conditionally excludes from the release build.

We are on the verge of handcrafting our own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of ATLTRACE? Not quite "the standard macro", but pretty close, I guess.

Comment: Sure. I just created a Win32 console project, included atlbase.h, and the ATLTRACE() output is nicely appearing in the output window.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a standard, best to roll your own.

However, you might want to consider `OutputDebugString(char*)`. It'll send output to the debug channel.

Comment: OutputDebugString calls would not be eliminated by preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [trace macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wyz8787.aspx) for this, which is a debug-only `printf`-style output function. Besides that, you might want to give the [`_RPT` macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42773424.aspx) a try.

Comment: Damn, missed the "non-MFC" solution :D You might want to take a look at how the macro is implemented though, maybe it does not use MFC internally at all.

Answer (score 0):

you must create your own debugging helpers by using debugapi functions

example:

'#'ifdef _DEBUG
    '#'define TRACE(x) OutputDebugString(x)
'#'endif